# Using two array's in one application with progressing the arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have the below code I'm trying to put together and I'm running into a Run-time error '9' subscript out of range. This does work through the first run through then errors. I don't see why it won't allow for the string to go forward. From what I'm reading it should go through the application changing the X values with Y value 1 and when completed with that set to go to the next Y and start the whole process again until the end of Y. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim Cat(1 To 10) As String

Cat(1) = "010" 'SD
Cat(2) = "020" 'FD
Cat(3) = "050" 'WVID
Cat(4) = "040" 'VID
Cat(5) = "030" 'MEM
Cat(6) = "080" 'ACC
Cat(7) = "060" 'HDMI
Cat(8) = "070" 'SSD
Cat(9) = "090" 'POWER
Cat(10) = "990" 'ZRM

Dim Month(1 To 12) As String
Month(1) = "January"
Month(2) = "February"
Month(3) = "March"
Month(4) = "April"
Month(5) = "May"
Month(6) = "June"
Month(7) = "July"
Month(8) = "August"
Month(9) = "September"
Month(10) = "October"
Month(11) = "November"
Month(12) = "December"

For Y = 1 To UBound(Cat)
    For X = 1 To UBound(Month)
        Month(X) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sheets(Month(X)).Columns("AO"), Cat(Y), Sheets(Month(X)).Columns("AG"))
    Next X
    Cells(3 + Y, 41).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Month(1), Month(2), Month(3), Month(4), Month(5), Month(6), Month(7), Month(8), Month(9), Month(10), Month(11), Month(12))
Next Y

End Sub
```

Comment: What language is this in?

Answer (score 0):

On the first run through the loop indexed by `X` you are computing a conditional sum of data stored in Sheet "January".  And then overwriting "January" with that value in `Month(X)`.  Let's say that that value is 42.  On your next run through the loop 42 is in `Month(X)` so you are looking for `Sheets(42)`, which probably isn't a valid worksheet.  I would try this instead.

```
dim temp as double
For Y = 1 To UBound(Cat)
    temp = 0#    '0 as a double.
    For X = 1 To UBound(Month)
        temp = temp + Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sheets(Month(X)).Columns("AO"), Cat(Y), Sheets(Month(X)).Columns("AG"))
    Next X
    Cells(3 + Y, 41).Value = temp
Next Y
```

This way we don't need to store all of the sums from each sheet, since we only use them to add them all together.